# Get Cloudflare R2 Public URL after uploading file using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3, cloudflare, cloudflare-r2

Is there a way to upload a file to Cloudflare R2 storage using `boto3` in Python, and get the public URL that it can be accessed at?

The files are being uploaded by doing

```
s3 = boto3.resource(
    "s3",
    endpoint_url=endpoint_url,
    aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id,
    aws_secret_access_key=secret_access_key,
)
bucket = s3.Bucket("my_bucket")
res = bucket.Object("foo.png").put(Body=f.read())
```

but the `res` reponse object returned does not appear to contain that looks like they can be used to construct the public URL.

Thanks!